# How to style Scroller according to the PSD

Tags: css

I need to style my custom scroll bar, as of now i didn't get any solution to achieve the desired results.i tried to use ::webkit-scroller properties but its not working.

Comment: This is not a quality question, you should post what you tried, what you expect, am closing unless you edit the question

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery plugin.

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

all you need to do is wrap entire code into main container and apply jQuery custom scroll plugin to it and apply you custom css accordingly...and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check this scrollbar plugins on below links

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0):

Try these pseudo elements and pseudo class selectors

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
   /* Select the top half (or left half) or scrollbar track individually */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
   /* Select the thumb when the browser window isn't in focus */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement:hover {
   /* Select the down or left scroll button when it's being hovered by the mouse */
}
```